# Unity GUILayout.TextField Refresh

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, textfield

I have a GUILayout.Textfield which I use to enter a new player name. However, the text in the textfield never gets refreshed although the value does change according to the console logs. Any idea how to get the text field to refresh?

```
private bool createProfile = false; 
private string playerName = "PlayerName";

void OnGUI()
{
  //Display window to enter player name.
  if (createProfile)
  {
    Rect createProfileWindow = new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 100, Screen.height / 2 - 35, 200, 70);
    createProfileWindow = GUILayout.Window(2, createProfileWindow, CreateUserProfile, "New player");
  }
}

void CreateUserProfile(int windowID)
{
  //Pop up window to introduce player name. Add 'create' button.
  GUILayout.BeginVertical();
  GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
  GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
  playerName = GUILayout.TextField(playerName, 50);
  GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
  GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
  GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
  GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
  if (GUILayout.Button("Create"))
  {
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("PlayerName", playerName);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
    createProfile = false;
  }
  GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
  GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
  GUILayout.EndVertical();
}
```

Comment: does this `playerName = GUILayout.TextField(playerName, 50);` keep reassigning the value back to itself? Could you use an intermediate variable?

Comment: It doesn't because the right values get stored. So if I type in there "John" it will store John but it will still display PlayerName on screen.